# Core dump while coloring graphs. Help please

Tags: c++, graph

So guys, I'm doing a code that my teacher asked in C++, and I am not accustumed to the language, so I'm having a problem with it.

The code is supposed to find the minimum amount of "colors"(I am using use integer to represent it), if Someone could help I would really appreciate.

Edit: Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/u4fYjVYR

The entry are graphs on a txt, it's supposed to do a minimum coloring of those and print the amount of colors I used.

Comment: Please tell us specifically what kind of problem. If it won't compile, what compiler errors did you get? If it compiles but produces wrong output, what output did you expect and what did you actually get? If it core dumped, at least tell us the error message, or even provide a stack trace from a debugger.

Comment: Oh my bad there, It compiled, and the error was Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Comment: @MatheusDavid:Please post full source code.

Comment: No, do not post "full source code". Post [a _minimal_ but complete testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to resolve the problem. I am assuming that you are using g++/gcc compiler.

1. Compile your program using `-g` flag. This helps in `debugging` your code.
2. Start `gdb <your program name>` and step through your code using `n` for next line and `s` for stepping into a function.
3. Use `print <variable name>` to print the values.

Now soon you will come to `line` which generates **segmentation fault**. If you are not able to resolve the problem, then share the code segment where the fault occurs.